# How to print @, with 2 different type of string

Tags: perl, quotes

I'm trying to write my first perl script. I find this a bit confusing since I only do C before this. I would like to print a string into a sqlfile and I'm having a problem to print a string that have **@**,. At the same time, I also need to print a variable.

This is my **code**:

```
.....
.....
Assume there is declaration and other function at the top
{
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=data.db" or die "Connection error: $DBI::errstr\n";
my $stmt = qq(SELECT * from menu;);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $stmt ) ;
my $rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;

$m=0;
while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
      $ID[$m] = $row[0];
      $NAME[$m] = $row[1];
      $PASSWORd_FLG[$m] = $row[2];
      $m++;
}
$k = $m;
my $stmt2 = qq(SELECT * from menuitem;);
my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare( $stmt2 );
my $rv = sth2->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$b=0;
while(my @row = $sth2->fetchrow_arrray()){
      $ITEM_ID[$b] = $row[0];
      $ITEM_MENU[$b] = $row[1];
      $ITEM_NAME[$b] = $row[2];
      $b++;
}
write_menu_to_sql_file($k,$c);
$dbh->disconnect()'
}

sub write_menu_to_sql_file{
      my $k = @_;
      my $c = @_;
      print (FILE, ">>$sqlfile") or die $!;
      print FILE ('declare @last_menu_id int');
      for($m=0;m<$k;$m++)
      {
      print FILE ("insert into My_Menu (NAME, PASSWORD) values ('$NAME[$m]', '$PASSWORD_FLG[$m]')\n");
      print FILE('set @last_menu_id = (select @@IDENTITY)');
           for($b=0;$b<$c;$b++){
           print FILE("insert into My_Item_Menu (NAME,ID,ITEM_MENU) values ('$ITEM_NAME[$b]', @last_menu_id, $ITEM_MENU[$b])\n");
           }
      }
 }
```

The **output** in the sqlfile will be:

```
 declare @last_menu_id int
 insert into My_Menu (NAME, PASSWORD) values ('Fikrie', 'Y')
 insert into My_ITEM_Menu (NAME. ID, ITEM_MENU) values ('WORK', ,'Fikrie')
 .......
 .......
 It will loop for all the data
```

As you can see, the @last_menu_id is declared as a variable, which I do not want. Instead I just want it to be as a string. So I tried changing all the word to use `' '` quote. But then, It doesnt recognize the other variable. How do I print a variable and a string that have @ in 1 line? I tried to write the code like this, but it gives error.

```
  print FILE("insert into My_Item_Menu (NAME,ID,ITEM_MENU) values ('$ITEM_NAME[$b]', "'@last_menu_id,'" $ITEM_MENU[$b])\n");
```

This is the **error** that I got:

```
 String found where operator expected near ""insert into My_Item_Menu (NAME,ID,ITEM_MENU) values ('$ITEM_NAME[$b]', "'@last_menu_id,'"
 (Missing operator before '@last_menu_id,'?)
 Possible unintended interpolation of @last_menu_id in string at ./testdb.pl line.....
```

Comment: escape `@` with `\\`?

Comment: It tells you exactly what the problem is - "Possible unintended interpolation of @last_menu_id in string". If you want more explanation, try adding `use diagnostics` to your code.

Comment: And *always* add `use warnings;` and `use strict;`. There's no point losing time over trivial  issues Perl can tell you straight away if only you ask it to.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I was using warning. But I didn't know about strict. This is totally new to me. I will take your advice and use it if I need to write another perl script after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape '@' character and try. Something like this: (Note the backslash before the @ symbol)

```
print FILE("insert into My_Item_Menu (NAME,ID,ITEM_MENU) values ('$ITEM_NAME[$b]', "'\@last_menu_id,'" $ITEM_MENU[$b])\n");
```